# Why does the vector member variable inside the object clear its elements one more time?

Tags: c++, vector

As title.
Below is my code, and here is [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://onlinegdb.com/YVMgBgJmS)

a.h

```
class B {
public:
    string n;
    B(string name) {
        this->n = name;
        cout << this->n<< " create" << endl;
    }
    ~B() {
        cout << this->n << " destory" << endl;
    }
};

class A {
public:
    vector<B> m_B;
    A():m_B(vector<B>{}) {
        cout << "class A create" << endl;
    };
    ~A() {
        cout << "class A destory" << endl;
    };
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
void addItem(A& _a,string n) {
    _a.m_B.emplace_back(n);
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    addItem(a, "a");
    addItem(a, "b");
    std::cout << a.m_B.size() <<"\n";
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

and terminal output is

```
class A create
a create
b create
a destory
2
Hello World!
class A destory
a destory
b destory
```

I would like to know why there is an extra sentence(a destory) in the fourth line?
At first, I thought it was due to "push_back" in addItem function,
but I get the same result when I use "emplace_back".
Thanks all.

know why there is an extra sentence(a destory) in the fourth line.

Comment: [std::vector is a dynamic array.Every time there isn't enough memory allocated to store elements, std::vector is trying to reallocate for a greater chunk of memory to store more elements. After that it needs to copy (move) your elements to other chunk implicitly calling dtors for previous elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67349392/12002570)

Comment: Kindly do the research before asking the question. As you can see there are many duplicates available for most(if not all) questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget that the vector may have to move elements when it runs out of capacity. Your vector starts empty, then allocates capacity for one entry, then runs out of capacity again and reallocates for two entries, then four, eight, and so on. [After each move, the old objects are destroyed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics/3109981) Here is a minimal change to observe it:

```cpp
class B {
public:
    string n;
    B(string name) {
        this->n = name;
        cout << this->n<< " create" << endl;
    }
    B(B&& o) noexcept
    : n(std::move(o.n))
    { cout << "move " << this->n << '\n'; }
  
    ~B() {
        cout << this->n << " destory" << endl;
    }
};

class A {
public:
    vector<B> m_B;
    A():m_B(vector<B>{}) {
        cout << "class A create" << endl;
    };
    ~A() {
        cout << "class A destory" << endl;
    };
};
void addItem(A& _a,string n) {
    _a.m_B.emplace_back(n);
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    addItem(a, "a");
    std::cout << "Capacity " << a.m_B.capacity() << '\n';
    addItem(a, "b");
    std::cout << "Capacity " << a.m_B.capacity() << '\n';
    addItem(a, "c");
    std::cout << "Capacity " << a.m_B.capacity() << '\n';
    std::cout << a.m_B.size() <<"\n";
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Prints

```
class A create
a create
Capacity 1
b create
move a
 destory
Capacity 2
c create
move a
move b
 destory
 destory
Capacity 4
3
Hello World!
class A destory
a destory
b destory
c destory
```

Comment: I've resolved it. Thank you!